# How do I pass a token in header and retrieve the value in cs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How do I pass tokens in headers and retrieve the value of token in the cs controller? I have used the following code in my javascript.

```
$http({
        url: vUrl+"Category/InsertCategories",
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        data: cats,
        params: { CompanyId: vCompanyId},
        headers: {
            "Authentication": "JsonToken",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
```

Comment: is your token custom token or token generated by any cloud services

Comment: Its auto generated.

Comment: Since it is authentication header and will be used in almost all calls that are made to   C# MVC, I would write interceptors (write a service, and append to $httpProvider.interceptors collection) in angular which would inject these tokens. In MVC side, every controller has Request property (this.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authentication"). Which angular version are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set authorization header many ways

1:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET/POST',
    url: 'url',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + "Jsontoken";
    },
    success : function(data) {
      //Success block  
    },
   error: function (xhr,ajaxOptions,throwError){
    //Error block 
  },
});
```

2:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET/POST',
    url: 'url',
     beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + "JosnToke"; 
    },
    success : function(data) {
      //Success block 
   },
   error: function (xhr,ajaxOptions,throwError){
    //Error block 
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the `Authorization` header in your request like this:

```
headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer JsonToken'
   }
```

and retrive the token in the controller:

```
var token = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using angular 1.x, then the below would give you some idea.

```
yourAngularAppName.service('AuthenticationHeaderInterceptor', [
    '$q',
    '$location',
    function(<dependencies if there are any>) {
      var self = this;
      config.headers['Authentication'] = "....";

      return this; // or whatever you want
    }
  ]);

yourAngularAppName.config([
  '$httpProvider',
  function(
    $httpProvider
  ) {

    // If you have token available at this time, you can do this as well instead of writing interceptor.
    //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Authentication"] = "....";
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthenticationHeaderInterceptor');    
  }
]);
```

in MVC Action:

```
public ActionResult TestAction()
{   
    var authenticationHeaders = this.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authentication");
    var authHeader = authenticationHeaders?.FirstOrDefault(vt => vt != "null");

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authHeader))
    {
        // return unauthorized
    }
    else {
       // continue with rest of the stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Solved it using the if else condition  as mentioned above.

Comment: @vidya, then why did you mark the answer as not useful?